# Можно ли передать имя переменной и значение в функцию?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, могу ли я изменить определенную переменную в функции? Пример есть функция:

```
function sum()
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    d = 0
    i = 0
    print(a + b + c + d + i)
```

Можно ли в ней как нибудь изменить определенную переменную, передав название этой переменной и значение
Например:

```
sl = {'a': 5, 'c': 2}
sum(sl)
```

И в итоге выведется 7.
Я просто даже не представляю как можно реализовать это!

Comment: Можно написать функцию, которая изменяет байткод функции, но вряд ли это то, что вам нужно. А вообще, вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: Наверно я сделал неудачный пример! Что я хочу попробовать на самом деле! Хотя я сомневаюсь что смогу понятно объяснить.

У меня есть такое окошко написанное на Qt 
http://joxi.ru/v29lRansGKG7Dm.jpg
Как видите в данный момент это окошко написано для добавления ткани! Если использовать это окошко для добаления пуговиц то надо изменить надписи (ткань на пуговицы, вес на кол-во, и т.д.)
если я буду редактировать запись, то мне надо вставить значения в LineEdit.
Я хотел написать функцию, которой я буду передавать имя виджета, и значение которое надо вставить.

Comment: Ну так сделай это имя и значение параметрами. Или упакуй в одну переменную, вроде `{'popup_title': u'Добавление пуговицы', 'fields': [{'title': u'Пуговица', 'type': ButtonSelector},...]}`.

Comment: Я примерно так и хочу сделать! Но я не знаю как в самой функции применять эти изменения!

Comment: Очень ГРУБЫЙ пример 

http://joxi.ru/12MjgENf4dMMpA.jpg

Comment: Добавил пример в свой ответ.

Comment: Что-то похожее на пример из последнего из последнего скриншота в комментариях реализовать можно, но это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я, прочитав все, правильно понял, что вам нужно, то делается это так:

```
def sum(values=None):
    if values is None:
        values = {}
    a = values.get('a', 0)
    b = values.get('b', 0)
    c = values.get('c', 0)
    d = values.get('d', 0)
    i = values.get('i', 0)

    return a + b + c + d + i
```

---

Если брать ваш [грубый пример](http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/05/09/0010/0371/717171/71/0c369ce8b6.jpg) из комментария, который, как мне кажется, наверное ближе к вашей задаче, я бы сделал так:

```
def set_settings(self, **kwargs):
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        getattr(self, name).setText(value)
```

Можно будет вызывать так:

```
obj.set_settings(label1='one', label2='two')
```

или так:

```
obj.set_settings(**{'label1': 'one', 'label2': 'two'})
```

и будет выполнен следующий код:

```
obj.label1.setText('one')
obj.label2.setText('two')
```

Comment: getattr(self, name).setText(value)
Вот что мне нужно было!!! 
Спасибо!
Но неужели нету ничего похожего для моего изначального примера?

Comment: @АлександрРублев, если вы используете Python2, то можно воспользоваться `exec`. Если же у вас 3-я версия, то простого способа это сделать (динамически модифицировать локальные переменные) нет. Хотя можно вместо переменных использовать словарь, тогда все просто.

Comment: Словарь вы имеете ввиду {} это? Но в моем случае это бы не помогло!

Comment: @АлександрРублев, глядите, так задачу решить просто нельзя (нельзя менять локальные переменные функции динамически, да и не нужно). Поэтому варианта у вас два: либо вам нужно переосмыслить задачу (это самый правильный вариант, ибо то, что вы хотите, -- очень странно и почти наверняка на самом деле не нужно), либо сделать решение возможным, и самый простой способ вместо локальных переменных хранить нужные вам значения в словаре, а уже его менять способом, показанным мною в ответе, просто вместо переменной `a` у вас теперь будет обращение к словарю: `d['a']`.

Comment: Спасибо! Я вас понял! Вы просто отлично помогли!

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно реализовать именно пример типа

```
sl = {'a': 5, 'c': 2}
_sum(sl)
```

который выведет 7, то можно сделать так:

```
def _sum(s):
    print(sum(s.values()))
```

Метод `values` объекта `dict` перечисляет значения в словаре.

Можно реализовать по-другому:

```
def _sum(**kwargs):
    print('kwargs:', kwargs)
    print(sum(kwargs.values()))
```

Тогда при вызове

```
_sum(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

выведется

```
kwargs: {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}
6
```

(вывод `kwargs` добавлен для демонстрации того, что в него попадет)

Также в эту функцию можно передавать и словарь в качестве аргумента, только при вызове нужно добавить перед ним две звездочки:

```
>>> s1 = {'a': 5, 'c': 2}
>>> _sum(**s1)
kwargs: {'c': 2, 'a': 5}
7
```

[Подробнее об аргументах функций](http://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
def _sum(a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, i=0):
    return a + b + c + d + i
```

Тогда вызвать можно так:

```
print _sum(a=5, b=2)
```

или так:

```
kwargs = {'a': 4, 'b': 2}
print _sum(**kwargs)  # всё внимание на звёздочки
```

А можно упаковать все параметры в один словарь:

```
def _sum(params):
    return params['a'] + params['b'] * params['mult']
```

тогда вызывать нужно так:

```
_sum({'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'mult': 3})
```

Comment: Да можно, НО! если у нас таких переменных не 5 а 15?

Comment: Если таких переменных 15, то надо разбивать на несколько функций.

Answer (score 0):

Если саму функцию вы не можете менять, то, я думаю, это нельзя так сделать. А если можете менять, то следует ввести аргумент. Его можно сделать составным, как у вас. Затем функция может использовать его как угодно, в т.ч. заменив какую-нибудь свою переменную значением того аргумента.

В общем, без изменения этой функции, передать имя этой переменной нельзя.